# Pandemic Legacy, February, and Epidemics

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

In Pandemic Legacy, February gives you

> Quarantine tokens. During the infect phase, if a city card is pulled and there's a quarantine token on that city, you remove the token instead of placing a disease cube.

But what happens if you have an epidemic outbreak on a such a city?  That is, when you draw a card from the bottom of the deck to infect,

> You normally place 3 cubes in that city.  But what if the city has a quarantine token in it?

What happens?

> Does the epidemic take effect as normal? Do you place 1 fewer cube per quarantine token? Does the epidemic simply not take effect and remove the quarantine token instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the marker.  That is the only effect.

> The Quarantine rules state (2nd paragraph) - When a player is instructed to add **any** amount of disease markers to the city (or any color), remove the quarantine marker instead of adding disease markers.

Of course,

> If the Quarantine Specialist is in the city, do not remove the token!